# Has anyone tried to create custom add product page and multilineitem page from opportunity

Tags: apex, visualforce, opportunity-lineitem

I have a requirement to create a VF page to overide the Add products button in opportunity lineitem from opportunity. I want to also move the selected products into multilineitem.jsp.

What the factors which we need to consider developing these pages. How is the price taken into the multilineitem page? Do we need to recreate the multilineitem page too if we are building the add product page, if there is no need then how do we pass the form values from VF page into multilineitem page.

The basic requirement is to have a extra field called quantity while searching and accepting qty in the search page and move this value into multilineotem.jsp 's quantity field

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at the [Snazzy Product Entry Screen](http://www.michaelforce.org/recipeView?id=a0G30000006eVxVEAU) from Michael Farrington. We use this internally and since it's an unmanaged package, you can customize it to your needs. I would think your "quantity" requirement would be easy to add to this.

This essentially replaces the add product page and the multiline edit page. It sounds like it might be exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: awesome.. this was what i was looking for